# Passing function as parameter, weird case

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I fear that it might come out as extremely cringy, but I don't know where else to ask.

For a while I thought if a function accepts another function as parameter it had to specifically say it in the type, i.e `f :: (a -> a -> a) -> b -> c`. So that I can pass something like `g :: a -> a -> a` as its first paramater and concrete type parameter as second, but nothing else.

But I have just discovered that I can apply `const :: a -> b -> a` to `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. And the result is weird `(+) const :: Num (a -> b -> a) => (a -> b -> a ) -> a -> b -> a`.

Also how is this `foldr :: ( a -> b -> b) ...` taking `(\b g x -> g (f x b))` as it's first parameter.

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f a bs =
   foldr (\b g x -> g (f x b)) id bs a
```

What's going on here? I don't even know how to call it, so that I can't do google search or use appropriate title on my question here.

Where can I learn about this? What is this called? What's the application and theory of it?

Comment: in `a -> b -> c`, the `a` itself can be resolved to `d -> e` which then the signature would be `(d -> e) -> b -> c`, or it can be resolved to `d -> e -> f` which then it would be `(d -> e -> f) -> b -> c`

Comment: In the case I wrote the function I wanna apply as first argument `(a -> b -> a)` has to be `Num` instance right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is what `Num (a -> b -> a) =>` says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *nothing special* about function types. A polymorphic function `a -> a` can obviously be used as, say, `Int -> Int`, or `String -> String`. But it can just as well be used as `(Char->Double) -> (Char->Double)`. In the example you've tried, you use basically

```
(+) :: (a->b->a) -> (a->b->a) -> (a->b->a)
```

Parentheses on the result can be ommitted, so this is

```
(+) :: (a->b->a) -> (a->b->a) -> a -> b -> a
```

If we supply a `const`, we then get

```
(const +) :: (a->b->a) -> a -> b -> a
```

So far I didn't bother about the `Num` constraint. That constraint is actually a problem, though it's not completely nonsensical – it is *in principle* possible to declare a `Num` instance for function types:

```
instance (Num r) => Num (a->r) where
  fromInteger = const . fromInteger
  f + g = \x -> f x + g x
  negate f = negate . f
  ...
```

Then the constraint `Num (a->b->a)` would be equivalent to `Num (b->a)`, which in turn would be equivalent to `Num a` alone. You can then actually use addition of functions like `const`: since this is a two-parameter function, the result of the addition will

```
> (const + \x y -> y) 1 1
2
> (const + \x y -> x*y) 1 0
1
```

and so on.

*However*, just because it's possible to define an instance doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea; it can also lead to weird unexpected behaviour. In particular, the `Num` instance for functions fails to fulfill the [field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29). The instance is not defined in the standard library, and IMO this is good. Hence, `(+) const` does not *actually* make any sense in Haskell.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Monoid` class has just such an unfortunate instance. It's valid, because monoids don't have cancellation or anything, but it's *weird*. Better would be `newtype Pull a b = Pull (a -> b)` with that instance, and `newtype Cat c a b = Cat (c a b)` with `instance (a ~ b, Category c) => Monoid (Cat c a b)`.

Comment: @dfeuer: true, though I recall there was some pretty nice application of that monoid instance, which wouldn't have worked as nicely with a newtype. (Nor with `Num`.)

Answer (score 1):

Any type variable can be instantiated with a function type, too.

The simplest example that gave me an "a ha" moment was to realise that:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
```

is just a special case of:

```
id :: a -> a
```

In other words, you can use `id` just like `$`, as an infix application operator:

```
ghci> negate $ 5
-5
ghci> negate `id` 5
-5
ghci> map ($ 5) [negate,(2*),(1+)]
[-5,10,6]
ghci> map (`id` 5) [negate,(2*),(1+)]
[-5,10,6]
```

You can literally define `($)` as `id`, just with the type narrowed down to functions:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) = id
```

So, in summary, anywhere you see a type variable like `a`, you can choose to instantiate it with a function type like `(b -> c)`.